# Type error, and then ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, graphing

So I had this:

```
def graph_data(dateList, countList, name):
xarray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
xarray = np.asarray(xarray)
myticks = dateList
plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))
plt.xticks(xarray, myticks)
plt.plot(xarray, countList, color='r', linewidth='3.0')
plt.ylabel("Activity")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.title(name + "'s Activity for the past 7 days")
plt.savefig("graph.png")
```

Which worked fine, but once I ran it on a different VPS (yes, i've already installed all the dependencies with pip), but then it gave me a type error, stating that in plt.plot, countList needed to be float, so I changed the code to this:

```
def graph_data(dateList, countList, name):
for n in countList:
    fixedList = []
    fixedList.append(float(n))
xarray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
myticks = dateList
plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))
plt.xticks(xarray, myticks)
plt.plot(xarray, fixedList, color='r', linewidth='3.0')
plt.ylabel("Activity")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.title(name + "'s Activity for the past 7 days")
plt.savefig("graph.png")
```

But then it gave me this error:

```
 "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
 ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (7,) and (1,)
```

so I added `xarray = np.asarray(xarray)` and `fixedList = np.asarray(fixedList)`
but it still gives me the shape error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you need to make sure that `countList` and `xarray` have the same number of elements. Assuming this to be the case, the problem is that you create an empty list in each loop iteration and append a single element to it. In the next iteration you recreate an empty list, again adding a single element.

Instead you need to create the `fixedList` outside the loop:

```
fixedList = []
for n in countList:
    fixedList.append(float(n))
```